# XCode 7.0.1 showing 8.4 simulator as downloaded, but it is not available in drop down list

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode7

XCode 7.0.1 shows the iOS 8.4 and 8.3 Simulators as already downloaded. But the iOS 8.4 simulator is not available to create new simulator instances in the drop down menu.

The iOS 8.3 simulator works as expected.

I would like to redownload this simulator to see if that makes it functional.

I found similar situations for XCode 6, but those solutions do not seem to work with XCode 7.0.1.

The iOS 8.3 simulator works just fine.

Output of "xcrun simctl list"

```
== Device Types ==
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
iPhone 6s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s)
iPhone 6s Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus)
iPad 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2)
iPad Retina (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina)
iPad Air (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air)
iPad Air 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air-2)
Apple Watch - 38mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-38mm)
Apple Watch - 42mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-42mm)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 7.1 (7.1 - 11D167) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-1) (unavailable, failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib)
iOS 8.1 (8.1 - 12B411) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-1) (unavailable, failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib)
iOS 8.2 (8.2 - 12D508) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-2) (unavailable, failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib)
iOS 8.3 (8.3 - 12F70) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-3)
iOS 9.0 (9.0 - 13A340) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0)
watchOS 2.0 (2.0 - 13S343) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-2-0)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 7.1 --
-- iOS 8.1 --
    Resizable iPad (A4954C9D-8B9A-4F8F-8527-5B3FFF3C38C4) (Shutdown) (unavailable, device type profile not found)
    Resizable iPhone (04586F63-3C12-40F7-B5DC-38933ED4C468) (Shutdown) (unavailable, device type profile not found)
-- iOS 8.2 --
    Resizable iPad (1A09F236-AE84-47BB-B83F-F9A37DC77A27) (Shutdown) (unavailable, device type profile not found)
    Resizable iPhone (AF1776A0-03CF-49F7-B50C-33AAFE49A8C6) (Shutdown) (unavailable, device type profile not found)
-- iOS 8.3 --
    Resizable iPad (F8D8DF8E-BA5E-4C56-AEE4-11D7D4B89B6C) (Shutdown) (unavailable, device type profile not found)
    Resizable iPhone (DFFC3E78-E340-433E-B06C-0E8F12A46496) (Shutdown) (unavailable, device type profile not found)
-- iOS 9.0 --
    iPhone 5 (AB9992C0-D015-4E41-B3EA-04BA7981B609) (Shutdown)
    iPad 2 (31F97C8D-7324-4922-ACAC-579C0FDDA8E8) (Booted)
-- watchOS 2.0 --
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-4 --
    Resizable iPad (5474A95A-D3A9-43BA-8CD1-C3DCA435C63D) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Resizable iPhone (241D1154-C8CB-4E05-9D7F-C4C14586A42D) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
== Device Pairs ==
```

Comment: Provide the output of 'xcrun simctl list'.  Is it installed in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes ?

Comment: No it is not installed there.

Comment: Then file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com please and include a screen recording showing the error in Xcode as well as the directory contents of /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

Comment: Thanks for that. However, it leaves me a little confused.
I do not have a ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles directory. Under CoreSimulator is a Devices folder and that is all.

Under the package contents of XCode there is a:
Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes that has iOS9.0.simtuntime

Comment: Look in /Library, not ~/Library

Comment: Then it looks like it hasn't been installed.  Try deleting that path and restarting Xcode to see if maybe that causes it to appear in the downloads section.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my confusion. In the /Library/... folder was an iOS 8.4.simruntime, but it's size was Zero.

Deleting that file corrected to display in the Preferences Downloads to show the iOS 8.4 simulator as not dowloaded.

I redownloaded the iOS 8.4 simulator and am able to create one, but now when I run that simulator, the title bar says iOS 8.4, but the General/About says Version 9.0 (13A340)

Comment: That is bizarre.  Definitely file a radar with a screen recording and ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*.log

Comment: OK, I deleted all the simulators from the Devices Management Page in XCode, rebooted my machine, and I am now able to successfully create an 8.4 simulator -Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the steps here in case anyone else has similar issues and also to mark this as answered.

There was a zero byte iOS 8.4.simruntime file in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes.

Deleting that file enabled the option to redownload the 8.4 simulator from the Preferences/Downloads screen. However, the simulator that was created from this action was reporting as 8.4 but was in fact 9.0

Deleting all the simulators using the XCode/Window/Devices screen and then rebooting the computer enabled being able to create a simulator that is the correct version.

Thanks to all who contributed ideas

Comment: I cannot locate /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/ infact there is only /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices and I too cannot see any simulator except iPhone6. Please help, I want to run it on iPads.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this from the location of dmg files in apple.com:

http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_4-8.4.1.1435785476.dmg

Comment: Am trying to work out how to install this in a way that XCode 7.0.1 will recognize it

Comment: Actually that is what I tried first. Also tried rebooting the machine afterwords.

Comment: Maybe you need to say that before posting a comment so that then you can get better help, It worked well for me after I pressed preferences then download and check and install after I installed this package. Sorry I cant be more help, as that all im trying to do.

Comment: Sorry John! I meant that I tried that after you gave me the link as that would be the way to go. I was then looking for other ways to use the package since that didn't work. I appreciate very much your giving me the link.